# Remove double alpha channel

Tags: gimp

I have 2 alpha channels.

I tried to delete the first one, but the "Delete channel" menu item is grayed out.

How could I delete it so that only the last alpha channel still remains?

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Please describe your question in detail and please mention technology/tools which you using. So community can get idea and help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The top four channels (R,G,B,Alpha) are the results of the full visible image and cannot be altered directly. You can't delete them but they aren't really duplicates anyway...

Also, the channel that you call "alpha" is just a separate channel, and isn't the alpha channel of the image (as it is it has no influence on the visible image, the Channels list is mostly a place where channels are stored for use in further operations). If you want to alter the opacity of the image, you have to add a a layer mask to a layer.